# Intellij Idea Liferay 6.2 server

Tags: intellij-idea, liferay-6

I try to install Liferay 6.2 server in Intellij Idea. I know the Liferay plugin just support the Liferay 7, but i need Liferay 6.2. Anyone succesfully installed Liferay 6.2 in Idea? I can't add server because Idea said "Invalid bundle type: Please check bundle location"

Answer (score 1):

As you already state

> I know the Liferay plugin just support the Liferay 7

it doesn't support your (old and outdated) version.

So: Don't use the Liferay plugin and install a Tomcat server (that happens to have deployed Liferay). And make sure to run [at least the patched version](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/security-patches-for-liferay-portal-6-2-7-0-and-7-1) but prepare to upgrade soon. There won't be any more bugfixes for 6.2, and don't bet on any less severe security fixes.

Bonus: You'll get all the latest Developer-Tools, compatible with the later versions, let alone the new features.